# Insert single quote and back slash on request.getParameter

Tags: jsp

How to insert single qoute (') and backslash () in an insert statement?

Currently, i have this

```
             String message = request.getParameter("message");

            insert = "INSERT INTO campaign (cid, uid, sender_id, content, dcs, Starttime, endtime, status, lastmodifiedid, creationtime, msisdnfile, number_subscribers) VALUES(" + cid + ", " + adminid + ", '"+ request.getParameter("sender_id") + "', '" + message + "', '" + dcs + "', '" +startDate + " " + request.getParameter("startTime") + "', '" + endTime + "', 'Pending', '" + adminid + "', NOW(), '" +  uploadedfile + "', '" + number_of_subs + "')";
```

I need to have if message.contains(') or message.contains('\') then it will replace with (\') or (\'). How can i do this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
insert = insert.replace("'", "\\'");
```

This will replace all your single quotes with literal backslashes in your insert statement

Comment: I need to replace message only, not all